# TypeError: dispatch is not a function at indexAction.js:66 at wrap (spread.js:25)

Tags: redux, react-redux

[Here is my code](https://coding.net/u/beyourhero/p/novel-react/git?public=true)

What should i do to fix this issue?

Comment: Please add your code in the question to make it easier to help you. The page you linked is very slow do load.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup `redux-thunk` in order to dispatch actions asynchronously. For more info go [here](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#installation) to the `redux-thunk` docs.

```
...
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
...

const store = createStore(novelReducer, undefined, compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk, routerMiddleware(history)),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
))
...
```

Comment: after us redux-thunk like this

`
const history = createHistory();
// const store = createStore(
//     novelReducer,
//     applyMiddleware(thunk)
// );
const store = createStore(
    novelReducer,
    undefined,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk, routerMiddleware(history)),
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )
);

`
issue alse exist